# How to unpack data in the format of 'SSSSLSS' in PHP?

Tags: php

I have 16 bytes with following format

```
short int, short int, short int, short int, unsigned int, short int, short int
```

when I use `unpack('SSSSLS', $data)`, it didn't return what I want. PHP attempts to use some format string as array key names, just like:

```
array(1) {
  ["SSSLS"]=>
  int(600)
}
```

Any way to generate the array of 6 numbers and just with number index?

Comment: wrap your unpack() in array_values(), so `$myArray = array_values(unpack('SSSSLS', $data));`

Comment: @MarkBaker the unpack('SSSSLS') doesn't work, it proudces an array only with one element like this: array(1) {
  ["SSSLS"]=>
  int(600)
}

Comment: @MarkBaker I just updated my question

Comment: Dont't you need a / for seperating each format 'S/S/S/S/L/S'??

Comment: @steven - I think it's 'SA/SB/SC/SD/LE/SF' to give you an associative array keyed on A,B,C,D,E and F (you can't use numerics for the index string); but something like `$result = array_values(unpack('SA/SB/SC/SD/LE/SF', $data));` should give a simple enumerated array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not how unpack works. This is the right code:

```
  array_values(unpack('S4l1/Ll2/S2l3', $data));
```

Basically you have to divide series with `/`s and you have to specify the number of occourrence if higher than 1. Also a name is needed because without that php will overwrite array keys.

The result of the unpack will actually be:

```
Array
(
    [l11] => short 1
    [l12] => short 2
    [l13] => short 3
    [l14] => short 4
    [l2] => int 
    [l31] => short 5
    [l32] => short 6
)
```

If you didn't use names it will be:

```
Array
(
    [1] => short 5
    [2] => short 6
    [3] => short 3
    [4] => short 4
)
```